# Removing lines of text in an ndjson file using python & regex

Tags: python, json, string

I am working on a python program and one of the things I need to do is to remove lines of text from a large ndjson file. So I was wondering the possibility of what I am trying to do is achieveable. Below is an excerpt from the large ndjson file (sorry as it is abit long, there's only two entries here). What I need are marked with "<<".

```
{   "took" : 27,   "timed_out" : false,   "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0   },   "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2008,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
================================FIRST ENTRY============================================
      {
        "_index" : "kibana-detections",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "alert:4ad48c3e-fc66-11ec-a8b4-5df1d1275a3c",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "alert" : {
            "name" : "Modification or Removal of an Okta Application Sign-On Policy",
            "tags" : [
              "Elastic",
              "Identity",
              "Okta",
              "Continuous Monitoring",
              "SecOps",
              "Identity and Access",
              "__internal_rule_id:cd16fb10-0261-46e8-9932-a0336278cdbe",
              "__internal_immutable:true"
            ],
            "alertTypeId" : "siem.signals",
            "consumer" : "siem",
            "params" : {                     << What I need - From Here ( '{' onwards) 
              "author" : [              
                "Elastic"
              ],
              "description" : "Detects attempts to modify or delete a sign on policy for an Okta application. An adversary may attempt to modify or delete the sign on policy for an Okta application in order to remove or weaken an organization's security controls.",
              "ruleId" : "cd16fb10-0261-46e8-9932-a0336278cdbe",
              "falsePositives" : [
                "Consider adding exceptions to this rule to filter false positives if sign on policies for Okta applications are regularly modified or deleted in your organization."
              ],
              "from" : "now-6m",
              "immutable" : true,
              "license" : "Elastic License v2",
              "outputIndex" : ".siem-signals-default",
              "maxSignals" : 100,
              "riskScore" : 47,
              "riskScoreMapping" : [ ],
              "severity" : "medium",
              "severityMapping" : [ ],
              "threat" : [ ],
              "timestampOverride" : "event.ingested",
              "to" : "now",
              "references" : [
                "https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Security/App_Based_Signon.htm",
                "https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/system-log/",
                "https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/event-types/"
              ],
              "note" : "## Config\n\nThe Okta Fleet integration, Filebeat module, or similarly structured data is required to be compatible with this rule.",
              "version" : 6,
              "exceptionsList" : [ ],
              "index" : [
                "filebeat-*",
                "logs-okta*"
              ],
              "query" : "event.dataset:okta.system and event.action:(application.policy.sign_on.update or application.policy.sign_on.rule.delete)\n",
              "language" : "kuery",
              "type" : "query"
            },                          << To here
            "schedule" : {
              "interval" : "5m"
            },
            "enabled" : false,
            "actions" : [ ],
            "throttle" : null,
            "notifyWhen" : "onActiveAlert",
            "apiKeyOwner" : null,
            "apiKey" : null,
            "legacyId" : "4ad48c3e-fc66-11ec-a8b4-5df1d1275a3c",
            "createdBy" : "elastic",
            "updatedBy" : "elastic",
            "createdAt" : "2022-07-05T13:28:02.747Z",
            "updatedAt" : "2022-07-05T13:28:02.747Z",
            "muteAll" : false,
            "mutedInstanceIds" : [ ],
            "executionStatus" : {
              "status" : "pending",
              "lastExecutionDate" : "2022-07-05T13:28:02.747Z",
              "error" : null
            },
            "meta" : {
              "versionApiKeyLastmodified" : "7.17.3"
            }
          },
          "type" : "alert",
          "references" : [ ],
          "migrationVersion" : {
            "alert" : "7.16.0"
          },
          "coreMigrationVersion" : "7.17.3",
          "updated_at" : "2022-07-05T13:28:02.747Z"
        }
      },
======================================SECOND ENTRY=========================================
      {
        "_index" : "kibana-detections",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "alert:4ad883de-fc66-11ec-a8b4-5df1d1275a3c",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_ignored" : [
          "alert.params.query.keyword",
          "alert.params.description.keyword",
          "alert.params.note.keyword"
        ],
        "_source" : {
          "alert" : {
            "name" : "AdminSDHolder SDProp Exclusion Added",
            "tags" : [
              "Elastic",
              "Host",
              "Windows",
              "Threat Detection",
              "Persistence",
              "Active Directory",
              "__internal_rule_id:61d29caf-6c15-4d1e-9ccb-7ad12ccc0bc7",
              "__internal_immutable:true"
            ],
            "alertTypeId" : "siem.signals",
            "consumer" : "siem",
            "params" : {                       << What I need - From here ('{' onwards)
              "author" : [
                "Elastic"
              ],
              "description" : "Identifies a modification on the dsHeuristics attribute on the bit that holds the configuration of groups excluded from the SDProp process. The SDProp compares the permissions on protected objects with those defined on the AdminSDHolder object. If the permissions on any of the protected accounts and groups do not match, the permissions on the protected accounts and groups are reset to match those of the domain's AdminSDHolder object, meaning that groups excluded will remain unchanged. Attackers can abuse this misconfiguration to maintain long-term access to privileged accounts in these groups.",
              "ruleId" : "61d29caf-6c15-4d1e-9ccb-7ad12ccc0bc7",
              "falsePositives" : [ ],
              "from" : "now-9m",
              "immutable" : true,
              "license" : "Elastic License v2",
              "outputIndex" : ".siem-signals-default",
              "maxSignals" : 100,
              "riskScore" : 73,
              "riskScoreMapping" : [ ],
              "severity" : "high",
              "severityMapping" : [ ],
              "threat" : [
                {
                  "framework" : "MITRE ATT&CK",
                  "tactic" : {
                    "id" : "TA0003",
                    "name" : "Persistence",
                    "reference" : "https://attack.mitre.org/tactics/TA0003/"
                  },
                  "technique" : [ ]
                }
              ],
              "timestampOverride" : "event.ingested",
              "to" : "now",
              "references" : [
                "https://www.cert.ssi.gouv.fr/uploads/guide-ad.html#dsheuristics_bad",
                "https://petri.com/active-directory-security-understanding-adminsdholder-object"
              ],
              "note" : "## Triage and analysis\n\n### .\n",
              "version" : 2,
              "exceptionsList" : [ ],
              "index" : [
                "winlogbeat-*",
                "logs-system.*"
              ],
              "query" : "any where event.action == \"Directory Service Changes\" and\n  event.code == \"5136\" and\n  winlog.event_data.AttributeLDAPDisplayName : \"dSHeuristics\" and\n  length(winlog.event_data.AttributeValue) > 15 and\n  winlog.event_data.AttributeValue regex~ \"[0-9]{15}([1-9a-f]).*\"\n",
              "language" : "eql",
              "type" : "eql"
            },                              << To here
            "schedule" : {
              "interval" : "5m"
            },
            "enabled" : false,
            "actions" : [ ],
            "throttle" : null,
            "notifyWhen" : "onActiveAlert",
            "apiKeyOwner" : null,
            "apiKey" : null,
            "legacyId" : "4ad883de-fc66-11ec-a8b4-5df1d1275a3c",
            "createdBy" : "elastic",
            "updatedBy" : "elastic",
            "createdAt" : "2022-07-05T13:28:05.532Z",
            "updatedAt" : "2022-07-05T13:28:05.532Z",
            "muteAll" : false,
            "mutedInstanceIds" : [ ],
            "executionStatus" : {
              "status" : "pending",
              "lastExecutionDate" : "2022-07-05T13:28:05.532Z",
              "error" : null
            },
            "meta" : {
              "versionApiKeyLastmodified" : "7.17.3"
            }
          },
          "type" : "alert",
          "references" : [ ],
          "migrationVersion" : {
            "alert" : "7.16.0"
          },
          "coreMigrationVersion" : "7.17.3",
          "updated_at" : "2022-07-05T13:28:05.532Z"
        }
      }, ....
```

So TLDR, what I need from the whole file is all the multiple entries from

```
{ 
   author:....
   ....
   ....
   type: ..
}
```

and remove all the rest.

So the question is: Is this possible to be done in a Pythonic way and/or with regex? Or is it too complicated to be done?

Comment: Don't do that.  Read the JSON in with `json.load`, manipulate the data structure, and write the JSON back out with `json.dump`.

Comment: You will find the *json* module very helpful for this then it's just a bit of trivial Python code needed to extract the relevant data. Do you then want to update the original file or create a new one?

Comment: @Stuart My aim is to just update the original file without needing to create another file.

Comment: @XynoYoo__ Does the updated file then have to be valid [ND]JSON ? I ask this because if you extract just what you've indicated in your question then it won't be. You should probably edit your question to show **exactly** what the output file would look like based on the sample data shown

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python json library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and read your ndjson file into a python dictionary.

With this you can write a small piece of code extracting the relevant data and dumping this back to a text file.

I do hope this helps